# List all files in all subfolders

Tags: windows, file-management, filesystems

In windows, is there any way to get a list of all files in a folder, including all the files within all the subfolders?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

List all Files Recursively

> C:`\`>dir /s

To save them to a file

> C:`\`>dir  /s /b>filelist.txt

View them a page at a time

> C:`\`>dir /s | more

Comment: Well, okay... This will work too. Just wondering why no one uses the standard Search function of Windows for this. :-)

Comment: @Workshop Alex: Because 1) recursive `dir` is just a little bit faster if it doesn't have to check any conditions; 2) it lets you save the names into a file.

Comment: @WimtenBrink: and how are you going to send windows search to another user?

Comment: You dont need to pipe to more, you just need the /p switch (does the same thing)

Comment: Remember the /a switch to include hidden files

Comment: Since the question doesn't mention directories, it should be `dir /a-d /b /s`.

Comment: @adolfgarlic  ctrl+a   shift right click -> copy as path

Comment: dir /a /s /b > FILES.csv

Answer (score 21):

Try tree /f. This should output the entire structure.

Comment: Which will be displayed as a tree, not a list.

Comment: You don't think the OP would consider that result a list?

Comment: I thought the tree command would have the best formatting, allowing you to clearly see the level of the subfolders.

Comment: it does have the best structure. can it be saved as a text file or html file?

Comment: tried `tree /f>filelist.txt` & it worked.

Comment: But this gives an ASCII visual, which OP did not ask for, and it doesn't include the full path with the filename. I think the DIR solution is ample.

Answer (score 5):

You will get [UnixUtils at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/), that will give you [`find.exe`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm).

You can then do the following for list of all files with folder paths.

```
cd Path\to\folder
find.exe . -type f
```

There are other forms of the Unix command that may be useful for you.
The output is more search-able compared to the native `dir` and `tree` commands.

---

Updated with input from `Johannes`.
In the `cmd.exe` shell

```
dir /b /s
```

works quite well for a recursive listing in the Widows formatted form,
(so you see "`C:\`" and the reverse slashes, '`\`').
I completely missed the "`\b`" in `Nifle`'s answer! (+1 for that now).

Comment: No need to install anything here, as `dir` is perfectly capable of this.

Comment: @Johannes, have you compared a Unix `find` output with a DOS `dir /s` or `tree` for that matter?

Comment: Have you ever used `dir /b`? :-)

Comment: @Johannes, actually I cannot remember if I did that in the DOS 6.22 days. Got more used to `find` and with Cygwin, never tried the dos commands (actually took me a moment to open `cmd` shell and avoid `/usr/bin/dir` to try that option. But, it does work; glad to learn that `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

I find this batch file every useful

DragDropListFile.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SET targetPath="%~1"
SET ToolPath=%~dp0

dir %targetPath% /b /s /a-d > "%ToolPath%list.txt"
```

Usage: Just drag the folder and drop it on the file DragDropListFile.bat, then a file called list.txt, which contains what you want, is created.

If you don't like drag & drop, try this batch file

ListFile.bat

```
ECHO OFF

SET crtPath=%~dp0

dir "%crtPath%" /b /s /a-d > list.txt
```

Usage: put the file ListFile.bat in the folder you want to list files, then run the file ListFile.bat, then a file called list.txt, which contains what you want, is created.

Comment: Thanks for such a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why so complex? Press Windowskey+F to start the "File Search" in Windows. On the left, go to "Look in" and select the option at the bottom called "Browse...". Select the (sub)folder where you want to search in.
Enter "*" (without the quotes) in the "All or part of the file name" editbox and start the search. Get some coffee when you're searching on a big disk with lots of data and just wait for this explorer-based search engine to show you a complete list. You can search it, open files directly and even narrow your search if need be.

Why do people forget this default search behaviour of Windows?

Comment: because it is not 1337? :-)

Comment: You would have a hard time getting that in a text file, for example.

Comment: True, but why would someone wants it in a text file? :-)

Comment: Note that this will (on Win XP at least) search *all ZIP files* in all subfolders as well. Which will be horribly slow. Which probably isn't what you want. Which can't be easily switched off. If there are no ZIP files, I agree that this is the best approach.

Comment: @Wim: Your 5-step process (Win+F, Browse, Subfolder, *, Start) is much slower than just typing "dir/s" (for a typist who types over 100 words per minute, and is used to doing stuff at a command prompt, so it is frequently pre-opened). Also, the process you mention has changed w/ Windows versions, while "dir/s" has been consistent. Also, your process requires pressing Win+F, which isn't always easy. Sometimes, even if a keyboard has the Windows key, that key may be more difficult to use, such as in Remote Access scenarios where the key might be used by the local computer instead of the remote

Answer (score 0):

`dir /s /w >files.txt` will get you most of the way there. It will keep the extensions. Then open `files.txt` in a text editor and either

- sort all the lines and delete the superfluous ones
- or remove them with a find and replace operation or 2.

  - The regex `^ +\d+ File.+\r\n\r\n Dir.+\r\n\r\n` got rid of the gaps and folder details between the individual folder files listings for me in Notepad++.
- Then just trim the top & tail of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread and I don't even know why I clicked on it since I didn't search for it,
but I'm really surprised how there's no answer listing the simple

```
*
```

as search query.
Either way, nowadays there's a setting for this in windows explorer `(all subfolders/ this folder only)`.